# Removing all 'stable' theme's CSS from a Drupal 8 custom theme

Tags: theming, 8

[image: CSS list]

I would like to remove all CSSs automatically included from *stable* theme:

```
/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/*
```

I can remove them one by one inside the `.info.yml` file:

```
stylesheets-remove:
  - 'core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css'
  - 'core/themes/stable/css/system/components/autocomplete-loading.module.css'
  - ...
```

Is there a way to remove all of them at once?

Something like:

```
stylesheets-remove:
  - 'core/themes/stable/css/system/components/*'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no wildcarding for the `stylesheets-remove` (FYI: there's [a FR](https://www.drupal.org/node/2097531) out there for it). However, you can use `libraries-override` to remove the library associated with the all CSS components you've highlighted:

```
libraries-override:
  system/base: false
```

It won't remove all CSS files in the stable theme, but it will condense removal of libraries that contain many CSS files.